# Adding large number of images to Flutter App

Tags: flutter, dart, apk, size, assets

I'm creating a Flutter App and I have to use about 600 PNG images (totalling 75 MB) I have tried adding the images folder and use it directly and the APK exceeded 100 MB size! how can I do this and avoid this huge APK size? Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use a cloud storage service like firebase,azure,google-cloud or any other simple server.
Then use CachedImage or Network Image widget and fetch them from the url. This is the best way to get large number of images with just less size of app

Comment: I considered it, but the application should work compleatly offline so I can't use any cloud service.

Answer (score 0):

For such a large amount of images I would suggest you to use cloud storage as Krish told you before. In your case that you want your qpp to work offline you could still save some images in your assets folder and some in the cloud so the appa could be still usable and in a smaller size

Comment: Seems it's the only way, SADLY. Thanks mate! :)